# What is wrong with this Terminal command? (fusermount -u /directory)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, terminal

What is wrong with this Terminal command? (fusermount -u /directory)

I am trying to unmount an encfs folder but I get this error message:

entry for /directory../ not found in /etc/mtab

Why and how can I unmount the encfs folder?

My method of trying to unmount is using this command: (fusermount -u /directory)

Ubuntu 15.10

Comment: This is a known issue ( https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/91736/32559 ) and there seem to be no satisfactory answer so far. Except, of course, of using sudo.

Answer (score 4):

I haven't found a satisfying answer to this.  The easiest is to run the command through sudo, for example

```
sudo fusermount -u /directory
```

I would prefer to keep everything as the user, instead of the super user but this looks like the only way to do it at the moment.